# How to renew section commands in latex3

Tags: sectioning, latex3, expl3

I'm trying to rewrite section commands using LaTeX3. For testing purpose, what I did is basically this:

```
\ProvideDocumentCommand \p { o m }
{   \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    { %
        \paragraph{\textsf{#2}}
    }
    { %
        \paragraph[#1]{\textsf{#2}}
    }
}
```

But I want to rewrite the `\paragraph` command so I could reuse any customization in a standard way. I've done some digging and obviously I need to get a grip on expl3, I saw multiple ways of doing this, like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109557/renewdefine-section-with-additional-argument) but I'm trying to reach something that might be distributed as a `.sty` class. I dig into [`skrapport`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/skrapport) class, but there's too much information. Is there anyone that could explain me step by step the process from the `\ProvidesExplClass` to command rewriting like any kind of section or a simple `\cite`?

Comment: Why? Why no simply learn how the sectional commands are actually being done, and then learn to configure those in a propper manner.

Comment: We've not yet got a fully-working set of class commands for LaTeX3 work. As such, we are still dependent on a lot of LaTeX2e stuff: I'm not sure there is currently a good alternative to using LaTeX2e commands mixed with LaTeX3 ideas.

Comment: @daleif I'm not sure I understood you right, but that's the aim of my question: "configure section commands in a proper manner, using expl3..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `skrapport` class defines sections with a simple pattern:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\paragraph{som}{
    \__skrapport_generic_section:nnnnn{paragraph}{4}{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
```

The first argument to `\__skrapport_generic_section:nnnnn` is the associated counter name level, the second the level, the third the possible `*`, the fourth the possible optional argument (short title) and the fifth, finally, is the full title.

Thus all you need, in order to change font for the `\paragraph` titles is

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand\paragraph{som}{
    \__skrapport_generic_section:nnnnn{paragraph}{4}{#1}{#2}{\sffamily#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

in your document preamble. Here's an example document.

```
\documentclass{skrapport}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand\paragraph{som}{
    \__skrapport_generic_section:nnnnn{paragraph}{4}{#1}{#2}{\sffamily#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\paragraph{This is a paragraph title}
Text follows.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but that would require me to use the `skrapport` document class, which I don't want to. What I need is a `.sty` file I can put all my customizations and simply call with `\usepackage` But that's the right direction, `skrapport.cls` has a `\cs_set:Nn\__skrapport_generic_section:nnnnn` calling all bunch of stuff. That the part of code I need to dig.

Comment: @nadous What class do you intend to use? Changing the formatting of titles is better done with a package such as `titlesec`.

Comment: Uh yeah! You're absolutely right, the `titlesec` package might very well suit my needs.