# Different indent only the first line in Section, subsection,

Tags: indentation, sections-paragraphs

I am writing a document with different indent (spacing) in all section (0.3in), all subsection (0.8in) and all subsubsection (1.4in).

### Only the first line in each paragraphs should be indented but the left margin is not change.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}      
\usepackage{geometry}   
\usepackage{lipsum}                     
\geometry{letterpaper}                           
\usepackage{multirow} 

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xunicode}

\usepackage{xltxtra}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\setmainfont{Times Roman}   

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titlespacing{\subsection}{1.1in}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}

\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{1.4in}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Second}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

---

[image: result]

But This is what I need is

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is change `\parindent` after `\section{}`. This can be done automatically redefining `\section{}`.  Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst} 

% redefining sections
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\oldsection{#1}\setlength{\parindent}{.3in}}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
I am writing a document with different indent (spacing)
in section (0.3in), subsection (0.8in) and subsubsection (1.4in). 
\end{document}
```

For `\subsection` and `\subsbsection` the procedure is  exactly the same.

I assumed that you do not need optional arguments in sectioning commands. Otherwise see [Renewdefine section with additional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109557/renewdefine-section-with-additional-argument)

Note that paragraphs after a title are not indented by default in English. If you want indent also the firs paragraph, use  also the `indentfirst` package as in the example.